# How to aggregate by each level level in a case study in SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, count, sum, case

```
select 
Count(CASE
    WHEN quantity * saleprice <= 400 THEN 'B'
    WHEN quantity * saleprice between 400 and 999 THEN 'S'
    WHEN quantity * saleprice between 1000 and 2099 THEN 'G'
    WHEN quantity * saleprice >=2100 THEN 'D' END) AS Level,
   c.customerid CountOfCustomers
from customers c join sales s on c.customerid = s.customerid join saleitem si on s.saleid = si.saleid
group by c.customerid
```

I need to aggregate by each level in this Case statement, but when I put the entire case statement in the group by clause I only get a one row output.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. It is unclear what you mean by "aggregate by each level".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want two levels of aggregation: first put customers into buckets according to their total sales, then count the customers per bucket:

```
select lvl, count(*) cnt_customers
from (
    select case 
        when sum(quantity * saleprice) <   400 then 'B'
        when sum(quantity * saleprice) <  1000 then 'S'
        when sum(quantity * saleprice) <  2100 then 'G'
        when sum(quantity * saleprice) >= 2100 then 'D'
    end as lvl
    from customers c 
    inner join sales s on c.customerid = s.customerid 
    inner join saleitem si on s.saleid = si.saleid
    group by c.customerid
) t
group by lvl
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you also explain the inner joins you used?